# Difference between "has been" and "is"

Tags: tense

> It **has been** better to keep money in a bank than to keep it under your mattress.
>   It **is** better to keep money in a bank than to keep it under your matress.

Which one of the above two sentences is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, "*is*" puts the statement in the present whereas "*has been*" implies the past *up until now*.

That said, they are not always mutually exclusive either. "*Has been*" is **not** always the same as saying something "*was*".

***Examples***

> The shop is busy this morning.

This refers to the present tense, so implies that it is still presently the morning, and that the shop is currently busy.

> The shop has been busy this morning.

This refers to the past (this morning) but it does not exclude the possibility that the shop is *still* busy. In fact it may still be morning too!

> The shop was busy this morning.

Using "*was*" implies that the shop is no longer busy.

But there are other examples where "*has been*" can be qualified to mean the past *or* the present:

> John has been president of the golf club.

Without any other details this would imply that at some point in the past John was the president of the golf club.

> John has been president of the golf club *since last year*.

This means that John *is still* the president of the golf club.